Cookie curl on two ec2s
My old project code is saving curl cookie to temporary file as below
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dir_tmp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dir_tmp);

it is running on 1 ec2
Now need to run on two ec2s with elb ec2 A and ec2 B, will saving like that cause curl cookie error
If not, does phalcon support saving cookie to database, I have not found a solution to be able to run the same code on two ec2s A and Ec2 B without curl cookie error
Hope to receive help

I guess "ec2" means "AWS EC2"? What does "with elb ec2 A and ec2 B" mean?

And what does "curl cookie error" mean exactly?

@Olivier load balancing

There are a lot of prerequisites sts, to be able to switch your app from running on a single machine to a lb or any other, one of these is to make your app stateless, depending on the local file storage making your app stateful, alternatively, you can switch to something like redis or shared storage.

@Olivier Elastic Load Balancer , chang request to EC2(A) or EC2(B)

@Olivier Does saving the file locally like that cause an error, currently running both ec2

OK, but why do you need to persist cookies in the first place?

@Olivier Cookies are used in Curl because they allow web applications to store information about the user and session state.
